# Como atualizar a janela tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Fiz um programa que joga dados. Utilizei a biblioteca gráfica tkinter para criar botões e labels. Eu utilizo o botão para ativar uma função que gera um número aleatório, porém a label não muda de texto, ou seja, o resultado do dado não aparece. Alguém sabe como procedo? Segue o código:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font
from random import randint



class Dice():



    def __init__(self):



        self.window = tkinter.Tk()




    def random_number(self):
        self.result = str(randint(0,100))   



    def elements(self):

        self.result = 'Resultado do dado'
        self.font = tkinter.font.Font(family='Arial', size=20)


        self.texto = tkinter.Label(text=self.result, width=20, height=2, font=self.font)
        self.cem = tkinter.Button(text='D100', width=10, height=2,font=self.font, command=self.random_number)
        self.quatro = tkinter.Button(text='D4', width=10, height=2,font=self.font)
        self.seis = tkinter.Button(text='D6', width=10, height=2,font=self.font)
        self.oito = tkinter.Button(text='D8', width=10, height=2,font=self.font)


        self.texto.grid(columnspan=2, row=0)
        self.cem.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.quatro.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.seis.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.oito.grid(column=1, row=2)








dado = Dice()
dado.elements()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o tkinter fazer algo que fique visível, você tem que passar o controle pra ele - depois de executar as funções e métodos que constroem a sua janela, adicionam os dados iniciais, etc, você faz isso chamando `tkinter.mainloop()` - nesse código, essa chamada seria logo abaixo da chamada a  `dado.elements()`.

Depois de chamar o `tkinter.mainloop()` o único código seu que vai rodar
vai ser o que estiver ligado a eventos do tkinter - no caso
o método `Dado.random_number` - que é passado como o `command` do botao `self.cem` (nenhum dos outros botões tem um  `command` nem é lido - não vão fazer nada).

mas então  -- o seu `.ramdom_number` tm que fazer mais coisas -se ele mudar só 
o  `self.result` - isso é uma string interna da sua classe que não está ligada ao tkinter - se quiser ver algo na interface, tem que fazer a chamada para atualizar o self.texto - pode ser simplesmente a linha

```
self.texto["text"] = str(self.resultado)
```

dentro do método `random_number`.

---

Faça essas duas coisas primeiro - depois que ver funcionando, vai ficar bem mais fácil entender como funciona o app com tkinter - é bem diferente de usar print e input - 
Aí você vai acrescentando os valores para os `command` dos outros botões.
Para não escrever um monte de métodos que fazem quase nada, pode usar a funcionalidade "lambda" ao escrever um command -

Por exemplo, em vez do `random_number` gerar um número fixo entre 0 e 100 (você tem um dado que dá "0"??) , ele pode aceitar um parâmetro, dizendo o qual dado usar, e você usa o `lambda` para passar esse parâmetro - se não fizer isso, vai ter que ter um método para cada tipo de dado:

```py
    ...
    def random_number(self, lados):
        self.result = str(randint(1, lados))   
        self.texto["text"] = self.result

    def elements(self):

        self.result = 'Resultado do dado'
        self.font = tkinter.font.Font(family='Arial', size=20)

        self.texto = tkinter.Label(text=self.result, width=20, height=2, font=self.font)
        self.cem = tkinter.Button(text='D100', width=10, height=2,font=self.font, command=lambda: self.random_number(100))
        self.quatro = tkinter.Button(text='D4', width=10, height=2,font=self.font, command=lambda: self.random_number(4))
        self.seis = tkinter.Button(text='D6', width=10, height=2,font=self.font, command=lambda: self.random_number(6))
        self.oito = tkinter.Button(text='D8', width=10, height=2,font=self.font, command=lambda: self.random_number(8))

...
dado = Dice()
dado.elements()
tkinter.mainloop()
```